# Airline Reservation Linked List Program

Tags: c++, object, linked-list, generalization

I currently have a program for an airline reservations database that uses `list<string>flight_list` and `string name` (which is solely the last name). I need to extend this program so that it stores a linked linked of Passenger objects instead of strings, I assume by changing it to `list<Passenger> passenger_list`? I'm having trouble understanding how to convert the functions within my class to accommodate for this change. The passenger object must contain each passenger's first name, last name and destination. There's a lot, but these are a couple of the functions as an example:

```
void read_from_file(list<string>& flist, string filename)
{
    string name;
    ifstream input(filename.c_str());
    while (input >> name) 
    {                   
        flist.push_back(name);
    }
    input.close();
}

void insert(list<string>& flist, string name)
{
    flist.push_back(name);
}

bool check_reservation(list<string>& flist, string name)
{
    list<string>::iterator i1, i2;
    i1 = flist.begin();
    i2 = flist.end();
    return (find(i1, i2, name) != i2);
}
```

I'm working with a main.cc class and a database.cc class. So yeah, any tips on how to generalize the classes would be appreciated please.

Comment: You may consider to ask this question at : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some observations that I hope helpful (but be careful: the following code is untested).

If your `Passenger` need first name, last name and destination, I suppose that there is a `Passenger` constructor with three string parameters.

I suppose that your `Read_from_file()` should become something like

```
void read_from_file(list<Passenger> & flist, string const & filename)
{
    string firstN, lastN, dest;
    ifstream input(filename.c_str());
    while (input >> firstN >> lastN >> dest) 
    {                   
        flist.push_back(Passenger(firstN, lastN, dest));  // for C++98
        // flist.emplace_back(fistN, lastN, dest); // for C++11/14
    }
    // input.close(); no need for close: file closed by destructor
}
```

Suggestion: pass parameters by reference, and using `const`, when possible.

Similarly, the `insert()` can be adjusted in a simple way (in two different modes, depending on whether you're using a recent C++ compiler or pre C++11)

```
void insert(list<Passenger> & flist, string const & firstN,
            string const & lastN, string const & dest)
{
    flist.push_back(Passenger(firsN, lastN, dest)); // C++98 version
    // flist.emplace_back(firsN, lastN, dest); // C++11/14 version
}
```

Less obvious how to `check_reservation()`. And really dependent from the C++98/C++11 question.

I suppose that you want a `check_reservation()` that want find a `Passenger` giving first name, last name *and* destination.

In C++11 is fairly easy (supposing your `Passenger` contains a `firsN`, a `lastN` and a `dest` member)

```
bool check_reservation(list<Passenger> const & flist, string const & firstN,
                       string const & lastN, string const & dest)
{
  return flist.cend() != find_if(flist.cbegin(), flist.cend(),
                                 [&](Passenger const & p)
                                     (return    (fistN == p.fistN)
                                             && (lastN == p.lastN)
                                             && (dest == p.dest);));
}
```

In C++98 you don't have lambda functions so is more tricky. You have to construct a functor for comparison; something like

```
struct person_eq : std::unary_function <Passenger, bool>
{
    string const & f;
    string const & l;
    string const & d;

    person_eq (string const & f0, string const & l0, string const & d0)
       : f(f0), l(l0), d(d0)
         {}
    bool operator() (Passenger const & p) const
     { return (p.firstN == f) && (p.lastN == l) && (p.dest == d); }
};
```

and your `check_reservation()` should become something like

```
    bool check_reservation(list<Passenger> const & flist, string const & firstN,
                           string const & lastN, string const & dest)
    {
      return flist.cend() != find_if(flist.cbegin(), flist.cend(),
                                     person_eq(fistN, lastN, dest));
    }
```

I repeat: this code is untested, so be careful.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

**Edit**

Sorry: if it's defined the `operator==` for your `Passenger`, your `check_reservation()` can be really easy

```
bool check_reservation(list<Passenger> const & flist, string const & firstN,
                       string const & lastN, string const & dest)
{
  return flist.cend() != find(flist.cbegin(), flist.cend(),
                              Passenger(firstN, lastN, dest));
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! I haven't tested it yet but this has definitely made it a lot more clear what I have to do for the rest of the functions also. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Define `class Passenger` correctly and everything else (fine passenger give a name etc. etc.) will be lot easier for you and anyone else who happens to be lucky one to maintain it in future.

Think through and implement following for `class Passenger`:

```
destructor
copy constructor
copy assignment operator
```

Good luck ! If you face specific issue with your C++ code, post it as separate question.

Reference:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Three